# Last form validation function is passing an error even though the first one registers the user

Tags: 7, forms

I wrote a custom user_login form validation function that calls user_external_login_register() to register and login the user, but the last validation function for the form calls form_set_error().

The form's #validate array looks like this:

```
validate (Array, 4 elements)

    * 0 (String, 32 characters ) vtiger_portal_user_form_validate
    * 1 (String, 24 characters ) user_login_name_validate
    * 2 (String, 32 characters ) user_login_authenticate_validate
    * 3 (String, 25 characters ) user_login_final_validate
```

user_login_final_validate() is here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_login_final_validate

Here is the code for vtiger_portal_user_form_validate() and the authentication function that it calls:

```
function vtiger_portal_user_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!vtiger_portal_authenticate($form_state)) {
    // Not a portal user. Let the other validation handlers run.
  } else {
    global $user;
    if($user->uid) {
      dpm($user);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Custom user authentication function
 */
function vtiger_portal_authenticate($form_state) {  
  $username = $form_state['input']['name'];
  $password = $form_state['input']['pass'];
  $testname = drupal_substr(drupal_strtolower($username),0,4);
  if ($testname == "dave") {
    user_external_login_register($username, 'vtiger_portal');
    return TRUE;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

I'm Seeing the "Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?" error and at the same time, being successfully logged in.  I have printed the $user object after calling user_external_login_register() and it shows that the uid is 9.

Can anyone help me figure out why I'm seeing an error from user_login_final_validate() when the user has obviously logged in successfully?

**Update: I've found the root of the problem.**

From the line 2121, user.module contains the following code.

```
// We are not limited by flood control, so try to authenticate.
// Set $form_state['uid'] as a flag for user_login_final_validate().
$form_state['uid'] = user_authenticate($form_state['values']['name'], $password);
```

user_login_authenticate_validate() sets $form_state['uid'] to FALSE so that later user_login_final_validate() sends it's error message.

Comment: Hello Arosboro, and welcome on _Drupal Answers_. May you report the code of `vtiger_portal_user_form_validate()`, which I think it is your custom form validation handler?

Comment: kiamlaluno, I've updated the post with the code you requested

Comment: Thank you. That code is useful to understand why you get that error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP mistakenly pasted user_login_final_validate() from D6 instead of D7. In D7, you avoid that error message by simply setting `$form_state['uid'] = [a number]`. You do that from within your custom #validate callback. Once you have done that, user_login_final_validate() will not throw an error and your form submission proceeds and thus login proceeds.

Comment: moshe, thanks for your help in #drupal-contribute. I am going to work on re-ordering the validation array so that my validation function can set $form_state['uid'] to true after user_login_authenticate_validate runs.

Comment: I added my validation function after the first two functions and before user_login_final_validate.  I added $form_state['uid'] = TRUE to my function as you suggested and the error message pertaining to the wrong username or password went away...  Unfortunately now there is another error from array_flip() in includes/entity.inc: `Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() line 178` and `Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() line 354.`  Why so many errors?!

Comment: the array_flip() errors were caused by setting $form_state['uid'] to true.  I had to set it to the actual uid from $user->uid.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the [`user_login_authenticate_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate) function will actually log the user in. The workaround is to unset the `user_login_authenticate_validate()` callback, and call [`user_authenticate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_authenticate) from `vtiger_portal_authenticate()` once you have performed your additional validation.

In order to unset the `user_login_authenticate_validate()` callback, you'll need to implement `hook_form_alter()`:

```
vtiger_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
    $key = array_search('user_login_authenticate_validate', $form['#validate']);
    if ($key !== FALSE) {
      unset($form['#validate'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: jhedstrom, is there a way to get both to co-operate?  Perhaps if I could put my custom validation function second to last.